# Adding a code to WordPress header based on local language into functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wpml

I have to add a Javascript code to a WordPress header based on the current language used by the website. We use WPML string translation. I want to write a function like this:

```
function add_customcode_header(){
?>
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru')
  {
    <script>
code 1
</script>
} 
  else
  {
<script>
code 2
</script>
  }
}
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header');
```

This function should place the script with `code 1` contents if the website language parameter is set to 'ru' and IF the language parameter is any other, it should add the `code 2` for other languages

The magic question is - will this function work properly?

**UPDATE:**

The proper solution that works:

```
function add_customcode_header(){
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru')
  {
    echo '<script>
              code 1
          </script>';
} 
  else
  {
    echo '<script>
              code 2
          </script>';
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall idea should work fine, however, in the example you posted, there were some syntax errors.

```
function add_customcode_header(){
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru')
  {
    echo '<script>
              code 1
          </script>';
} 
  else
  {
    echo '<script>
              code 2
          </script>';
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header');
```

or

```
    function add_customcode_header(){

    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ru')?>

        <script>
    code 1
    </script>
    <?php
      else ?>
    <script>
    code 2
    </script>
<?php
    }  
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header');
```

Should both be syntactically correct, and it really just matters what you're more comfortable with.

Comment: @twelvell Awesome! Does it make sense to you? Understanding what's going on is way more important than it actually working imo.

Comment: Yes, what I`ve done wrong is mixed JavaScript with PHP in a wrong way. It should be placed separately. Thanks again for pointing out these two ways.